# Facing issues with a discord.py "hug command"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a Discord.py bot that responds to commands with a random image that has been specified, here is my code:

```
hug_gifs = ['https://c.tenor.com/nHkiUCkS04gAAAAC/anime-hug-hearts.gif']
hug_names = ['Hugs you!'] 


@bot.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed [
        colour=(discord.Colour.red()).
        description = f"{ctx.author.mention} {(random.choice(hug_names))}"
    )
    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(hug_gifs)))

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your command?

Comment: It comes up with:
File "/home/mapler/Discord/Bots/ace/main.py", line 30
    colour=(discord.Colour.red()).
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You put a dot instead of a comma

Comment: I updated the code to make it have a comma but now it comes up with:
  File "/home/mapler/Discord/Bots/ace/main.py", line 29
    colour = (discord.Colour.red()),
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Maybe it's a specific import? Try having `from discord import Color` with your other imports and using American English `discord.Color.red()`

Comment: The arrow points are the = sign so it might have something to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes when you are trying to create the `discord.Embed`:

- When passing the arguments to the `discord.Embed` object, you are starting the initializer with a `[`, which should be changed to `(`. In Python the `[` and `]` shall be used only to create a list or to reference any of its positions.
- You are using a dot `.` as separator for the different arguments taken by the constructor of `discord.Embed`, but that should be a comma `,` .

Here is your corrected code:

```py
hug_gifs = ['https://c.tenor.com/nHkiUCkS04gAAAAC/anime-hug-hearts.gif']
hug_names = ['Hugs you!'] 


@bot.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed (
        colour=(discord.Colour.red()),
        description = f"{ctx.author.mention} {(random.choice(hug_names))}"
    )
    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(hug_gifs)))

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```